# NestJS with TypeOrm: How do I save authentication information using @BeforeInsert and @BeforeUpdate?

Tags: mysql, express, jwt, nestjs, typeorm

I have a simple extension of BaseEntity using TypeOrm for which I want to force some property values obtained from the request when doing CRUD operations.

```
import {
    Column,
    BaseEntity,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
    BeforeInsert,
    BeforeUpdate
} from "typeorm";

import { IsOptional, IsNumber, IsDate, IsString } from "class-validator";

export class CrudEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    @IsOptional()
    @IsNumber()
    id?: number;

    @Column({ nullable: true, default: null })
    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    scope?: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true, default: null })
    @IsNumber()
    @IsOptional()
    client?: number;

    @Column({ nullable: true, default: null })
    @IsNumber()
    @IsOptional()
    user?: number;

    @Column({ type: "timestamp", default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" })
    @IsDate()
    @IsOptional()
    created?: Date;

    @Column({ nullable: true, default: null })
    @IsNumber()
    @IsOptional()
    createdBy?: number;

    @Column({ type: "timestamp", nullable: true, default: null })
    @IsDate()
    @IsOptional()
    modified?: Date;

    @Column({ nullable: true, default: null })
    @IsNumber()
    @IsOptional()
    modifiedBy?: number;

    @BeforeInsert()
    public beforeInsert() {
        this.setClient();
        this.created = new Date();

        // @TODO Get info from JWT
        this.createdBy = null;
    }

    @BeforeUpdate()
    public beforeUpdate() {
        this.setClient();
        this.modified = new Date();

        // @TODO Get info from JWT
        this.modifiedBy = null;
    }

    public setClient() {
        // @TODO Get info from JWT
        this.scope = null;
        this.client = null;
    }
}
```

I need a way to retrieve the decoded JWT token sent in the request headers in order to save who insert or updated what at what time.

I have read about request scopes, injection, etc. I haven't been able to figure it out or find a simple solution to a simple problem someone else must have certainly faced at one point while writing a NestJs backend service.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried subscribers? https://typeorm.io/#/listeners-and-subscribers/what-is-a-subscriber, another idea could be you create a Base Repository of your base Entity that wraps the TypeOrm Repository so you can inject the current user as a dependency in your custom base Repository and set it to the base entity before saving.

Comment: I will definitely look at this all I have found are overengineered methods like cls-hooked, zone.js and request-context.

Comment: Ended up setting these values in the CrudService class and disabled cascades. Original problem was that users could post data with values on relations and entities inside cascades would not be properly set.

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind adding your solution here?

Comment: It's more of an alternate solution because I had to disable cascading, therefore only the root record gets updated from the service not the relations. I say a real solution is pending NestJs changes or a simpler alternative to cls-hooked and the rest for getting the request context scope.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `@BeforeInsert` and `@BeforeUpdate` was not triggered because I was passing DTO instances to my service.

If you want them to be triggered, you must convert it in their final (here its `CrudEntity`) using `plainToClass(CrudEntity, dto)` for instance. Can be quite annoying when your DTO includes data types that differs from your final entity class